# How to establish communication between flex and python code build on Google App Engine

Tags: python, apache-flex, google-app-engine

I want to communicate using flex client with GAE, I am able to communicate using XMl from GAE to FLex but how should I post from flex3 to python code present on App Engine.

Can anyone give me a hint about how to send login information from Flex to python 
Any ideas suggest me some examples.....please provide me some help

Regards,
Radhika

Answer (score 2):

I've been able to use flex on GAE using the examples found at [The GAE SWF Project](http://gaeswf.appspot.com/) which uses [PyAMF](http://pyamf.org/).

Comment: Thanks do you have any worked out example for that.....atleast posting some information and accessing it in python

Answer (score 0):

Do a HTTP post from Flex to your AppEngine app using the URLRequest class.