# Send Data From Flex to Python (GAE)

Tags: python, apache-flex, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm working on a project that runs off Google App Engine (Python) which stores various user details inside GAE's datastore. I have Flex content which users can use and once done the Flex app needs to send data to the Python backend to 'mark' the user off for that task. Any suggestions?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to establish communication between flex and python code build on Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/854353/how-to-establish-communication-between-flex-and-python-code-build-on-google-app-e)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have flex send a request to the Python server. COuld be a form post or JSON data or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the following:
http://fernandoacorreia.wordpress.com/2008/07/15/flex-and-python-project/

It may help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [pyamf](http://www.pyamf.org/index.html) gateway for django and tipfy. I have a [similar open source project](https://github.com/ocanbascil/captionmash/tree/master/server/captionmash) with django-flex communication resting at github, so you can also check out.